# Error with GCC pragma to suppress a warning

Tags: c, gcc, gcc-warning

I have used the following code to suppress warnings:

Starting from line number 25:

```
#pragma GCC diagnostic push
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wincompatible-pointer-types"
#include <main.h>
#pragma GCC diagnostic pop
```

But I am getting the following warnings:

```
main.c:25: warning: expected [error|warning|ignored] after ‘#pragma GCC diagnostic’
main.c:26: warning: unknown option after ‘#pragma GCC diagnostic’ kind
In file included from main.c:28:

main.h: In function ‘libstart’:
main.h:55: warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type
main.h:58: warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type
main.c: At top level:
main.c:28: warning: expected [error|warning|ignored] after ‘#pragma GCC diagnostic’
```

Is there an issue in my code? Is there another way to suppress a warning from a specific file?

Comment: What version of gcc are you using?

Comment: I'm guessing it's an old 4.X one as push/pop was added in 4.6 and that warning in 5.1.

Comment: This is a warning which you should never ever disable though. Particularly not on gcc. You will end up hiding lots of severe bugs. The correct solution is to use some manner of cast, on case to case basis.